# page content function for wp_insert_post

Tags: wordpress

I want to add two text fields of username and password in the page content. Basically i am making my plugin. I have made a page which is connected to my plugin. I want to add content in this page by using function.

my page code is:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_install_function'); 
function my_plugin_install_function() {  
    $post = array(
        'page_template' => '', 
        'comment_status' => 'closed', 
        'ping_status' =>  'closed' ,
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_name' => 'Checklists',
        'post_status' => 'publish' ,
        'post_title' => 'Checklists',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_content' => 'my_function()'


    );//insert page and save the id 
    $newvalue = wp_insert_post( $post, false ); //save the id in the database
    update_option( 'hclpage', $newvalue );
}
my_function()
{
// A login form will be here.
}
```

Is it possible ??? what will be the best way to do it in the plugin file of wordpress ???

Comment: Ok, now that your function is readable. What problem do you have putting `'post_content' => 'please, post content'`?

Comment: thanx for your reply. I want to do it like this => 'post_content' -> 'myfunction() here'

Comment: But did you try to do that? What `myfunction()` will do?

Comment: can you give me facebook id or email. I can explain all my problem there.

Comment: my_function() will have a login form. Mind it i am using it in my plugin file.

Comment: Please, **[edit]** the question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add content I did not use function. But I use php variable.

```
 $form = '<form action="..../wp-content/plugins/wp-link-with-parse/php-sdk/test.php" method="post">
 <label for="username">Username:</label>
 <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
 <label for="password">Password:</label>
 <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
 <div id="lower">
 <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
 </form>';
```

to assign content use:

```
'post_content'=> $form
```

Answer (score -1):

i know this post is from 5 years ago, but i'm currently trying to do a wordpress plugin, and i found a solution for adding content to a custom page in wordpress, what i did is to create a .php file with all the content, including php code, and then include that code in my post_type page by creating a variable and adding that file to that variable with file_get_contents, something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grszd.png)

hope it can be useful

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't use images for information that is easily communicated in text. Images are not friendly to search or copy & paste or visually impaired people.